# How to set crop starting position with imgscalr?

Tags: image, javax.imageio, imgscalr

I have tried to use imgscalr library with the following crop method:

```
Scalr.crop(image, height, width);
```

But it always crops starting at the left upper corner of the image. Can I tweak this behavior to start in the right bottom corner or center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely - just use the other `crop` operation that takes [x,y,width,height](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#crop(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp...)) arguments.

Comment: but anyway I can calculate x and y on its own

Answer (score 2):

```
//center
Scalr.crop(image,
    (image.getWidth() - width) / 2, (image.getHeight() - height) / 2,
    width, height);

//top left:
Scalr.crop(image, width, height);

//top right:
Scalr.crop(image,
    image.getWidth() - width, 0,
    width, height);

//bottom left:
Scalr.crop(image,
    0, image.getHeight() - height,
    width, height);

//bottom right:
Scalr.crop(image,
    image.getWidth() - width, image.getHeight() - height,
    width, height);
```